# Using this.state in method with argument this.state.parameter

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner in React JS, my problem is that I have a method in my component that has an argument `(this.state.t)`. The error message is, `"t" is not defined`. This is my code:

```
this.state = {
     t: 5 ,
     a:this.give(this.state.t)
  }
...
give(B){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use `this.state` inside its own declaration. You should be setting the state in the `componentDidMount` function like

```
this.state = {
     t: 5 ,
     a:null
  }
...
handleClick = () => {
    var a = this.give(this.state.t);
    this.setState({a});
}

give(B){
...

}

<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much , il is the best solution .

Comment: But i have an problem , i should not use the componentDidMount :( .

Comment: Why can't you use it

Comment: because with componentdidmount my function will start at each starting of my app but i like it starts only if i click the button.

Comment: That is infact easier. You need to have a onClick handler on your button and call the handleChange function. I have updated the code for that

Answer (score 0):

I think, we cannot assign a variable inside a state, you can do one thing, 
initially in constructor assign variable `t`. thereafter call `this.give()` function at the end of constructor.

```
constructor(){ 
super() 
this.state = {t:5}

this.give = this.give.bind(this)
this.give(this.state.t)
}

give(a){
youroperation with a 
}
```

Comment: Thank you friend for your answer.

Comment: are you sure ? any way to assign a variable inside a state ?